# buildroot problem

Tags: linux, embedded, buildroot

Ok, you can tell by my name that I'm new to this, so please understand if any "errors & warnings"

I am trying to build rootfs image for at91sam9260 controller, for which I'm using buildroot. The problem is that it is not able to download the package "ftp://ftp.uu.net/graphics/jpeg//jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz". And on top of that, I'm also not able to download it manually. It is showing some authentication requirement. I have googled for this without any solid results. Pretty sure I'll find an answer here though.

$uname -a

Linux tri-desktop 2.6.28-11-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 01:58:03 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

... if this helps.

If anyone has encountered this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Things seems like it should be on SuperUsers? -- ftp://ftp.uu.net seems to require a l/p, I assume buildroot has a requirement for this jpegsrc file? is this just libjpeg that it wants?  You may want to consider just getting it from a different source like http://freshmeat.net/projects/libjpeg/

Comment: not sure exactly. All I know is that it is downloading packages it requires and putting it in a dir "dl".i manually downloaded other packages it could not download and put them in that dir, and it worked. But 'm not able do it for this package.
I'm just following a manual that does not discuss this problem.

Comment: I would just get the package from another place you trust other then uu.net - their FTP does not seem to want to let me in no matter what l/p I tell them so ::shrug::

Comment: A suggestion for future questions: Your title here is very vague, and doesn't really describe the problem.  Something like "Problem downloading package from uu.net with buildroot" would be better, as it would give people an immediate idea of the issue (and whether they could help) when they're skimming a list of issues.  The more details you can put in the title, the better -- in this case, the problem apparently had nothing to do with buildroot, and was simply that uu.net was having a short-lived FTP glitch.

Comment: sorry 'bout that, will take care next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative place to get the software - I'd just get it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/quirkysoft/downloads/detail?name=jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz&can=2&q=) instead should be the same thing as that of the ftp.uu.net site.

Comment: found another one
http://dir.filewatcher.com/d/GNU/Other/jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz.613261.html

Answer (score 2):

Put in `anonymous` as the user, and your email address as the password.

Comment: From the terminal: `wget --ftp-user=anonymous --ftp-password=your@email.com  ftp://ftp.uu.net/graphics/jpeg//jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz `
  should work if Ignacrio is right, but uu.net did not seem to accept this when I tried it...

Comment: Normally I'd say "in your browser", but you've stated that putting the file in the appropriate location didn't work. My next step would be to modify the URL in the appropriate config file, changing it to `ftp://anonymous@myusername%40mydomainname:ftp.uu.net/...`.

Comment: o/p of the above...

tri@tri-desktop:~/Desktop/test/buildroot-v23434$ wget --ftp-user=anonymous --ftp-password=aditya.gawand@gmail.com ftp://ftp.uu.net/graphics/jpeg//jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz
--2010-01-15 20:19:36--  ftp://ftp.uu.net/graphics/jpeg//jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz
           => `jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz'
Resolving netmon.iitb.ac.in... 10.200.13.50
Connecting to netmon.iitb.ac.in|10.200.13.50|:80... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ...